# Python- Does select() will work with UDP functions(recvfrom() and sendto() )?

Tags: python, sockets, select, udp

Is `select.select()` function from `select` module will work with the UDP functions - `recvfrom()` and `sendto()`?
I want to make program use select function, and I know that it works with TCP functions - send and recv but I want to build UDP server that use the select functions.

So, is it possible to work with `select` function with the UDP functions `recvfrom` and `sendto` ?

Comment: Select does work with UDP if that is all you are asking.

Comment: @user_ABCD yeah basically what i'm asking is if select will put in rlist all the clients that do sendto() , and in wlist all the clients that do recvfrom() like it does on TCP functions send and recv

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Python's select() function works for UDP as well as TCP sockets. And to address the follow-up in your comment to user_ABCD, with UDP sockets, select() returns the same information as it does with TCP sockets.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#module-select):

> The return value is a triple of lists of objects that are ready:
>   subsets of the first three arguments. When the time-out is reached
>   without a file descriptor becoming ready, three empty lists are
>   returned.

If you pass arguments to select() that include UDP sockets, those sockets will be included in the return lists, if they are in fact ready to be read or written to.